# Не доходит файл до сервера Apollo Server + Express

Tags: reactjs, fileupload, graphql, nextjs

Всем привет. Делаю по примеру здесь: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/data/file-uploads/.

Вот код на сервере:

```
type File {
  filename: String!
  mimetype: String!
  encoding: String!
}

type Mutation {
  singleUpload(file: Upload!): File!
}

async singleUpload(_parent, { file }) {
  const result = await file
  console.log(result)

  const { stream, filename, mimetype, encoding } = result

  // console.log({stream, filename, mimetype, encoding})

  return { filename, mimetype, encoding }
}
```

На фронте:

```
const SINGLE_UPLOAD = gql`
  mutation SingleUpload($file: Upload!) {
    singleUpload(file: $file) {
      filename
    }
  }
`

const UploadOneFile = () => {
  const [singleUpload] = useMutation(SINGLE_UPLOAD)
  const [imgURL, setImgURL] = useState("")

  const handleFileChange = (e) => {
    const { target: { validity, files: [file] } } = e

    console.log({validity, file})

    singleUpload({ variables: { file } })
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <input type="file" onChange={handleFileChange} required />
      <img src={imgURL} />
    </div>
  )
}

export default UploadOneFile
```

В итоге `console.log(result)` на сервере показывает пустой объект. Может чего-то не хватает?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Короче, нашел ответ на зарубежной версии stackoverflow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58772089/apollo-server-express-not-receiving-upload-object

Нужно просто на клиенте добавить createUploadLink вместо createHttpLink и все будет работать!)

```
const httpLink = createUploadLink({
  uri: 'http://localhost:4000/graphql',
})
const authLink = ...
const client = new ApolloClient({
  link: authLink.concat(httpLink),
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
})
```